# What are the possiblites of order of element $a$ in a Group

Tags: group-theory

Let $H$ be a normal subgroup of $G$ and let $a \in G$. If the element $aH$ has order $3$ in the group $G/H$,

and order of $H$ is $10$. What are the possibilities of order of $a$?

So, element $aH$ has order $3$ in the group $G/H$ $\implies$ $a^3 \in H$

Since order of group $H$ is $10$, Therefore by Lagrange theorem $o(a^3) | 10$

Now after this step I am little confused, From here How can I proceed to find the order of element $a$

Any hints ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any element of $H$ has order 1,2,5 or 10. Since $a^3 \in H$, $a$ must have order 3,6,15 or 30.

Comment: @NickyHekster If $a$ has order 1, then the element $aH$ in $G/H$ has order 1, not 3. If $a$ has order 2, then the element $aH$ in $G/H$ has order 2, not 3.

Comment: Remember that $aH$ has order 3, so 3 **must** divide the order of $a$

Comment: You are totally right.